# How to call a JavaScript function with parameters on C#

Tags: c#, javascript, httpwebrequest

I want to call a JavaScript function with HttpWebRequest or WebRequest in C#. I don't want to use a webbrowser which I can call invokemember.

Here is my code:

```
public void MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data)
{  

       request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
        {
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = method;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
        }
       string postData = data;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        dataStream.Close();
}
```

```
MyWebRequest("http://example.com", "POST", "javascript:onclick=\"try(1,3)\"");
```

`try` is a JS function which has two int parameters. I want to call the onclick method, but how can I pass parameters to the function.

```
onclick="try(1,3);"
```

Comment: sorry, I edited my code !! I forgot to add some code.. now its ok

Comment: The javascript function resides on the page you're fetching with `WebRequest`?

Comment: You are doing a HTTP POST request to a server. It happens you pass some JavaScript with the request. Do you now expect to server will "execute" that code? If no, then you will receive a response, which depends on the server. If by chance the server responds with the same JavaScript code, do you expect that the response, on your side, will "execute" the code? Just trying to understand the question...

Comment: I thought that server will execute that code? is not possible? Because I could make it with a webbrowswer.. maybe It uses similar technology with webrequest, doesnt it?

Comment: @HarunAbi: Javascript needs the backing of the javascript engine in order to run; something, to my knowledge, the `WebRequest` isn't going to give you, and thus you're not going to be able to execute JavaScript functionality from or within a request. Also, as a follow up to a later comment, JavaScript is **client-side**, not server-side. So the Client (i.e. `WebRequest` or alike) would need to ability to run it, not the server itself.

Comment: I'll vote to close this question. @HarubAbi, is not possible with those classes, perhaps is better to stick with WebBrowser class.

Comment: aha.. thank you Brad, its clear for me.. and you mean, I have just one option which is using a webbrowser? If yes, It will be slow ..

Comment: @AdrianIftode, I see.. thank you for your interested. But people can learn that is not possible like me.. :)

Comment: @HarunAbi: If you need the functionality of the site, yes, the `WebBrowser` is probably the best way to go. And it's only "slow" because it has to load all the plugins like JVM, JS Engine and any other abilities the page requires to operate.

Comment: really thank you Brad, its so clear.. Okay I'll use a webbrowser.. :)

Comment: Why would you want to call JavaScript from c#, use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so this isn't an open-ended question...

`WebRequest` is essentially a "glorified" socket library that establishes a connection to and from a web server. It's not more than a means to transfer data between a client (the app using the `WebRequest`) and the server hosting the site.

For the same reason if you viewed the `dataStream` (referencing your code) you'd only see HTML markup and not actual layout elements and colors, styles, etc., javasript also won't work. HTML needs a rendering agent, JavaScript needs an engine.

So, if you need the ability to use JavaScript included on the page, `WebBrowser` is your best bet. It will load up any libraries/plugins necessary to run any JavaScript found on the page. It may be slower, yes, but that's because it's giving you a lot more than just transferring data (it's also rendering HTML, executing any initialization scripts, and binding to any elements that the page has defined to be necessary for the aesthetics.)